# Weird Flex But Ok

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

What does "**Weird Flex But Ok**" mean? I looked up on the Internet but I couldn't get any more!

Answer (score 2):

In contemporary Internet slang, a *flex* is a boast.

This word is often used in the contemporary Internet cliché (oops, I mean *meme*): weird flex, but OK.

The meaning is fairly literal, once you take into consideration the slang meaning of *flex*: That is a strange boast (a strange thing to boast about), but that's OK.

Here's an unhip source explaining the meme (which probably does mean it's morphed into a cliché already): https://www.dailydot.com/unclick/weird-flex-but-ok-meme/